# Is there better way to deal with database in WM instead of dataset?

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm developing windows mobile application (first one) on WM6 and I'm using dataset to deal with database but looking for something else better ... is there any framework here or there to use (instead of connecting directly with DB) ?

Answer (score 0):

No, I think that is generally the way it's done.

You could, of course, create an n-tier application that contains all of your database logic in a separate wrapper. Perhaps that is what you are accustomed to working with, but if no one has written that for you, then you get to write it.

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue thatneary any rm of bstratonin a dataaccess lyer(DAL)is better than the immensely slow memory hog knwon as the DataSet.  You rarely (and thankfully) see any articles or tutorials using DataSets any longer - that includes for the desktop.

Instead there has been a proliferation of frameworks and models that abstract the data away from the business logic.  Things like NHibernate and Entity Framework are getting to be more commonplace and they make your code a boatload more readable, maintainable and often a better software citizen.

Since WinMo/Windows CE has such a small market compared to the desktop, few of the large frameworks are supported.  I don't view that as all bad, though, as most desktop framework that get "ported" down to the CF perform abyssmaly (MCSF anyone?).

After having to write virtually the same data access code over and over on projects over the years, I finally coalesced out [an ORM framework for the device](http://orm.codeplex.com/) (that also works on the desktop) that actually performs rather well.  Well enough that I use we use it in all projects that require data access, both device and desktop, and it's been meeting all my needs.

Comment: Thanx .. I'll give it a try and tell you about the results